# What does this symbol mean in the Starcraft chat portrait?

Tags: starcraft-2

What is the little symbol in corner of the portrait, in Starcraft 2's list of friends?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Real ID 'broadcasting' feature:

[image]

I assume your friend send a "*short status message*" for all his Real ID friends to see.